How to make Copilot Edits to show on right Tab
I'm using Visual Studio Code, and the "Edit with Copilot" pane currently displays on the left side of my screen. I’d like to move it to the right side instead. I don’t need the old Chat window, and I prefer to keep the new "Edit with Copilot" pane on the right for better accessibility and workflow.
I've tried looking for settings but haven't found a clear way to make this change. Could someone guide me on how to move the "Edit with Copilot" pane from the left to the right side of the screen?
Here's a screenshot of my current layout:


I have the same question and I have tried everything, it doesn't look like its possible to dock it to the right. As someone who uses Visual Studio proper, I find VSCode's window (mis)management to be very frustrating, I wish they would just let everyone decide how to manage their windows as they see fit.

Hold onto the window and drag it over to the right side

It was simple as holding on the window and dragging to the right

+1 this is documented here. To drag you have to click on the icon on the very left edge of the window's title bar.

Not absolut sure, but maybe you can configure it in the Customize Layout Settings.

